# HTML TextArea doesn't get bigger when I increase the columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My text area is not expanding horizontally when I increase the number of columns. It is stuck at around 5 columns or so. No matter how big I increase it, it stays the same size. The rows change with no problem.

This happens no matter where I put a text area on my Wordpress website. Leads me to believe it's a styling issue, but I don't know what's causing it.

```
<textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Comment: I dont see any problem with it.. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LXATR/

Comment: As you stated that its happens within your website.. we cant solve your problem without looking at your website code.. Please make fiddle with your website code, use width other wise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is using CSS. L

```
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" name="message" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
```

You can change width, height as you wish.

Comment: thank you. I did an inline style before and increased the width, I don't know why it didn't work then

Answer (score 0):

you must have in your css something like bellow :

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```